# how to get the value of a variable declared within a function

Tags: javascript

I'm a beginner in JS. In my personal project I want to use a datalist of colors to change the div color.

I managed to do it with select. But it doesn't work with datalist. So I decided to console log the value of the variable declared in the function but I get the error: x is not defined. How to make it work? (It's probably a basic question)

```js
const selectSection = document.querySelector(".select-section");

function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("my-select").value;
  selectSection.style.backgroundColor = x;
}

console.log(x);
```

```html
<label for="my-select">Pick a color:</label>
<select name="" id="my-select" value="Choose the background color" onChange="myFunction()">
  <option value="default">default</option>
  <optgroup label="Warm Colors">
    <option value="red">red</option>
    <option value="orange">orange</option>
    <option value="yellow">yellow</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Cool Colors">
    <option value="green">green</option>
    <option value="blue">blue</option>
    <option value="purple">purple</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

Comment: Declare a global variable which will be outside of `function` and initiate it later in the `function`

Comment: You don't have any elements with class `.select-section` in that markup.

Comment: When I use: let x; outside the function I get undefined; I want to get its value in the console log.

Comment: I want to get the value of x in console log.

Comment: move the `console.log` inside the function.

Comment: If you add in that missing div that code will work. But yes, that variable is scoped to the function, so move the log inside the function. [But there isn't much point since the code works...](https://pastebin.com/jPH9tSm1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two options:

##### 1

```
const selectSection = document.querySelector(".select-section");

let x;

function myFunction() {
  x = document.getElementById("my-select").value;
  selectSection.style.backgroundColor = x;
}

myFunction()

console.log(x);
```

##### 2

```
const selectSection = document.querySelector(".select-section");

function myFunction() {
  const x = document.getElementById("my-select").value;
  selectSection.style.backgroundColor = x;
  return x
}

const x = myFunction()
console.log(x);
```

Remember to never use `var`

Comment: In your first example, the `console.log(x)` will execute before `x` gets its value.

Comment: The statement "Remember to never use `var`" is incorrect, there are still some uses where `var` should be used

Comment: Aside from golfing or legacy code, I don't know any. I can agree to `never use var if you are a beginner`

Comment: There is nothing wrong with `var` when you require function level scoping.

Comment: Why not use `let` then?

Comment: You absolutely can, but that doesn't make using `var` incorrect. `var` is still a valid syntax in the language. And, in fact, using `var` could be more readable for some folks as a very explicit way of showing your intentions to have just a function scoped variable.

Answer (score 2):

**First**
please don't use the `var` keyword in your code read this [article](https://dev.to/mindninjax/stop-using-var-for-declaring-variables-2p3a) to know the reason

**Second**
to solve this problem

1. try to declare your variables in the global scope:

   `let x; // in global scope (outside the function)`
2. and assign a value inside the function:

   `x = document.getElementById("my-select").value;`

Answer (score 0):

You can declare the variable outside the scope of the function, but you must make sure to only access that variable AFTER the function has completed, otherwise the code will run BEFORE the function executes and the variable will not have been altered yet.

```js
const selectSection = document.querySelector(".select-section");

let x = null;

function myFunction() {
  x = document.getElementById("my-select").value;
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = x;
  // If this line executes, we know x has been modified, so
  // it's safe to try to access it outside of the function
  showX();
}

function showX(){
  console.log(x);
}
```

```html
<label for="my-select">Pick a color:</label>
<select name="" id="my-select" value="Choose the background color" onChange="myFunction()">
  <option value="default">default</option>
  <optgroup label="Warm Colors">
    <option value="red">red</option>
    <option value="orange">orange</option>
    <option value="yellow">yellow</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Cool Colors">
    <option value="green">green</option>
    <option value="blue">blue</option>
    <option value="purple">purple</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```